# installation gone awfully wrong?

Tags: ejabberd

I have installed the platform using the .run script
Two dirs appeared in /opt/ejabberd and /opt/ejabberd-20...

I started the services registered users and  connected played along fine
Pidgin also sent a file from one member to another.
BUT I noticed no offline messages were stored and sent later.

I started digging with `ejabberdctl` to find out why and I came up with this ungoogleable problem:

All module directives result in no modules reports
E.g.

./ejabberdctl modules_installed
nothing returned...

./ejabberdctl module_check mod_offline
Error: error
Error: not_available

Of course I should apologize if all these happen because I am a new user

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: It is ejabberd on an old open suse 11 platform

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed no offline messages were stored and sent later.

Well,

1. check in ejabberd.yml configuration file that mod_offline is enabled... Maybe that module is not enabled in the default configuration of the ejabberd version you installed.
2. If the module is listed in that file, and that file is read by ejabberd, then check in the ejabberd log files if there is any error message.
3. If you made other changes in the configuration, like setting SQL storage, etc, maybe they broke offline storage.
4. Or maybe the feature works correctly, but you don't understand how it works. When user1 sends a message to user2 in your server, but user2 is not connected, then the message is stored in an offline table. Later when user2 logins with a positive presence, offline messages are sent.
5. You can also check if the offline messages are stored or not. If using the default mnesia database, see in ejabberd webadmin -> vhosts -> your vhost -> Users -> user2 -> Offline messages

> ./ejabberdctl modules_installed nothing returned...

That's normal, because those commands refer **only** to contributed modules: the additional modules that you can later install from https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib to add some specific function.